# Netty send final message to ChannelGroup before closing

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm new with Netty and I'm trying to implement a Websocket server. I follow the examples provided in source code.

I do a graceful shutdown of my netty server and I want to catch that and send a last message to all connected channels and then close my server. How is this possible? I use a DefaultChannelGroup

Netty version 4.0.24 and I have a websocket implementation similar with the examples provided

and from the following resource: https://gist.github.com/aolshevskiy/1653087

Implement maybe a BeforeCloseListener?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean "catch that".  Before you do the graceful shutdown why not just send your message?  Based upon your description the link you provided is not your actual code? Can you provide a link to your code, or a reduced set of code to demonstrate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have managed to do that by adding a DefaultChannelGroup and sending a message to all connected channels, the problem was that I was adding each channel at an early stage and I was ending up having NioServerSocketChannel instead of NioSocketChannel which would do the job for me.